# react-bootstrap-table-next - Uncaught ReferenceError: BootstrapTable is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I use ReactJS in MVC4 application - using jsx syntax.
When using react-bootstrap-table - everything looks fine.
After upgrade to react-bootstrap-table-next - I receive the error - bootstraptable is not defined.
What can be the reason?
Maybe I should have Import bootstraptable from 'bootstraptable'?

In TextTable.jsx file:

```
class TextTable extends React.Component {
render() {
    const products = [];
    const columns = [{
        dataField: 'id',
        text: 'Product ID'
    }, {
        dataField: 'name',
        text: 'Product Name'
    }, {
        dataField: 'price',
        text: 'Product Price'
        }];

    return (
        <div>
            <span>Hi!!</span>
            <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={products} columns={columns} />
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render
(
    <TextTable />, document.getElementById('content')
);

    in Index.cshtml file:
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="~/node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table-next.js"></script>
<link href="~/node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/wwwroot/dist/TextTable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your component:

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
```

Make sure you install the library such as : `npm install react-bootstrap-table-next --save`

After this:

You no longer need `<script src="~/node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table-next.js"></script>` in your `index.html`

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-table-next)

Comment: Thanks, but when adding the line:
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
there is an error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-table-next#usage), you must import `BootstrapTable` like so:

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
```